# Assembly Return Address Replace

Tags: assembly, x86, exploit

I have seen that by replacing the return address on the stack, the `EIP` can be made to point at addresses that are part of the stack.
But, for example, `JMP` needs the programmer to specify the code segment when doing far jumps between segments. What happens when you replace the return address? Does the `CS` change?

Comment: No, mainstream operating systems use a flat memory model, `CS` is constant, jumps are near, and all addresses are offsets only. (Unless you are doing fancy things like mixing 32 and 64 bit for example.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`far call` / `far ret` exist too, along with the `far jmp` you mentioned, but nobody uses them either.  (All mainstream OSes use a flat memory model where `cs` is constant.)

Any normal compiler-generated code will be using [near `ret`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/RET.html), so it only pops into `EIP` / `RIP`, not a wider value into `CS:EIP`.

---

If you want your exploit to switch to the OS's 64-bit user-space code segment selector value in a 32-bit process (or vice versa), you're going to have to gain enough control to run a `far jmp` / `call` / `ret` in your payload, or jump to one that exists as part of another instruction somewhere or in data on an executable page.

Beware that the OS may not preserve your modified `cs` in some cases.  [For example, some ways of invoking Linux system calls set `cs` to the kernel's `__USER32_CS` constant.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46087730/what-happens-if-you-use-the-32-bit-int-0x80-linux-abi-in-64-bit-code)